# Proper Way to Create Executable from PY File

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mysql-python, mysql-connector, self-contained

I'm not able to create a proper self-contained executable from my Python code.

I recently worked on a project. I coded in Python where I've used MySQL. The modules I've used are tkinter, random, customtkinter and connector from mysql. I also use .png images from my own laptop, using them in the PhotoImage function of tkinter.

The problem is I tried to create an executable from the final code, using the pyinstaller command in cmd. The executable was created in the dist folder successfully, and it works. I realised the application won't run if I delete or misplace the other files generated along, that is the dist and build folders. I used --onefile in pyinstaller and it works without the dist and build folders now.

Now my issue is with running the executable in different laptops. I shared the exe file created by --onefile, but running the exe file doesn't work anymore, meaning it is not self-contained (not needing my laptop's software, like MySQL, the data in MySQL, AND the pictures I have in my laptop).

[Error that shows when laptop running exe file does not have MySQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xRsA.png)

[Error asking for pictures stored in my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXhFQ.png)

How do I make the exe file ACTUALLY self-contained? I want it to be independent in spite of using all the above mentioned stuff.

P.S. Please use simpler words as I don't have much experience with coding.

Comment: Please focus your question on a single problem and give it a more descriptive title. It looks like you're asking two questions: "how do I include a MySQL server with my program" and "how can I include images / data files in an executable made with pyinstaller"

Comment: Do note that the requirements of "being self contained" and "interacting with a MySQL server" are really at odds unless you're planning on hosting a MySQL server somewhere.

Comment: Don’t use MySQL, use sqlite and package it with your executable. [Difference between SQLite and MySQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-mysql-and-sqlite/amp/)